# Dangers of Colbalt Chloride Paper Burning

Tags: toxicity

I am a science technician and foolishly decided to heat a small amount of cobalt chloride paper on a glass petri dish over a Bunsen. Unfortunately the petri dish broke and the paper hit the metal gauze under and burnt. I immediately put the rest of the paper in water and opened the window.

The cobalt chloride paper was white (not pink) and approximately 3 x 1 cm in size. I am very concerned that I have released very toxic material and would welcome any comments.

Comment: LD 50 80 mg/kg  i.e. over a gram for a grown man and the content in the paper isn't all that big... I wouldn't be very concerned. Copper chloride dissolved in a large amount of water will produce insoluble cobalt carbonate over time, so it isn't all that environment unfriendly, and it is a vital microelement, so it will be eventually recycled by environment. That said, work in a fume hood when possible in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good story to share ...

- It is not surprising that a rapid heating of a Petri dish provided by a Bunsen burner cracks the former.  By application of the heat, the glass wants to expand, to dilate; hence you swirl test tubes over a Bunsen, provided your lab still has access to natural gas.
- A more gentle heating of the glass, to dry the paper impregnated by $\ce{CoCl2}$ were *gradual* heating on a heating plate.  By this you equally would obtain the colourless, waterfree form, in a more safe manner (no open flames, no ignition).
- Yes, $\ce{CoCl2}$ is considered *toxic*, and dangerous for the environment.  It is suspected *carcinogen*. You set yourself unnecessarily in danger, not only because of the flames, but that the dry salt, too: finely dispersed in air, it is then easily inhaled.  You won't die on the spot, however, *do not repeat this*. And *ChemSE is not a subsitute for a physician.*
- Depending where you did this, disposal of heavy metal, and aqueous solutions of heavy metals (like $\ce{CoCl2}$) is regulated by law, and hence the rinse with water was probably fine to extinguish the fire, but the waste water generated is not normal household waste.  Especially if it were on a larger scale.
- For future reference: look up safety informations of chemicals you intend to work with, chemical suppliers include them in MSDS sheets. In chemistry lab classes, students are requested to get familiar with these information *prior* to performing the experiments.